# Compare matching array index values in Yii2 search

Tags: php, mysql, search, yii2

I am developing REST API in Yii2. In search query i want to achieve this

```
 WHERE ((`variant_name` LIKE '%size%' AND `variant_value` 
 LIKE '%12%') OR (`variant_name` LIKE '%color%' AND `variant_value` LIKE '%12%'))
```

the variant_name and variant_value are an array sent in the URL.
The corrsponding Yii2 code i am using right now is  as follows

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['or',
['or like', 'pvo.variant_name', $this->variant_name],
['or like', 'pvo.variant_value', $this->variant_value]])
 ->groupBy(['pvo.product_variant_id'])
 ->having(['count(product_variant_id)' => count($this->variant_name)]);
        ;
```

Which is generating the following SQL

```
AND ((`variant_name` LIKE '%size%' OR .`variant_name` LIKE '%color%')
 OR (`variant_value` LIKE '%13%' OR `variant_value` LIKE '%56%')))
```

But i want varaint_name[0] and varaint_value[0] in single bracket having AND condition with  varaint_name[1] and varaint_value[1] like mentioned above.
Kindly guide me how should i go about it in Yii2?

**Update 1**
Sample URL
http://localhost:8080/online-malls/api/web/v1/products?expand=product_variant_options&variant_name[0]=size&variant_value[0]=13&variant_name[1]=color&variant_value[1]=56

Comment: in Which wya the variant_name and variant_value  are sent in the url  ? .. please update your question adding  sample of your url or of the qay you forming the param for the url

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks for the response . I have updated the question

Comment: I have posted  and answer  hope i what you are  looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an array  in get  then you should use the array value in param  eg:

```
  $query->andFilterWhere(['or',
    ['or like', 'pvo.variant_name', $this->variant_name[0]],
    ['or like', 'pvo.variant_value', $this->variant_value[0]], 
    ['or like', 'pvo.variant_name', $this->variant_name[1]],
    ['or like', 'pvo.variant_value', $this->variant_value[1]],
    ])
     ->groupBy(['pvo.product_variant_id'])
     ->having(['count(product_variant_id)' => count($this->variant_name)]);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. But what if i don't know in advance length of an array? Do i need to loop through this? or is there any other workaround.

Comment: For me the simple way is the use of a loop for prepare the porper  filter condition ..

Comment: Thanks again. One more thing the fourth OR operator is creating a syntax error . Could you please fix it too?